# useEffect causing component to re-render infinitely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

I am adding items to the wishlist and once it is added I am trying to re-render the Heart icon to have a number on it to indicate that the Item has been added to the wishlist. What I want to achieve is similar to Twitter's like button, when someone likes the post the number of likes increases immediately. So, in my case when someone likes (wishlists) the product it will increase the number on top of Heart icon. I am using local storage to get the items that are added to the wishlist, and I can re-render the Wishlist component when a new Item is added inside the effect but it makes the component to re-render infinitely which is giving me a warning of `Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded`

Here is my effect;

```
const [wishlist, setWishlist] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
     if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
       const wishlistStorage =
       localStorage.getItem("wishlist") === null
       ? []
       : [...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("wishlist"))];

     if (wishlistStorage.length > 0) {
       setWishlist(wishlistStorage);
  }
}


}, [wishlist]);
```

If I remove the wishlist from dependancy array, I need to refresh the page to see the correct number of items. What am I doing wrong here and what would be the best way to approach this. Thank you!

Comment: Of course it does, when you make it dependent on the state you're updating inside it. Only put values in `useEffect`'s second argument that you want to cause a re-run.

Comment: You are telling React to only run the useEffect when the wishlist state changes, but you are changing the wishlist state within the useEffect. Therefore, when you change the wishlist for the first time, the useEffect runs because the wishlist has changed, but then the useEffect has changed the wishlist, which triggers it to run again and again and again.

Comment: useEffect will re-render your component when 'wishlist' changes and you are changing value of 'wishlist' in useEffect by calling 'setWishlist'. This is the reason why it stuck in infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the wishlist variable from the dependency array.

When you call `setWishlist`, it'll update the state, the dependency array will check that it has changed and will call the useEffect once more, thus the infinite cycle.

With an empty dependency array, it'll only run when your component mounts, fetching the data from your local storage and initializing your app. From there on, all you need is to handle the state locally and updating the localstorage with any new wishlist items, but that useEffect seems to be for initialization only.

UPDATE #1

The core issue here was that OP was using LocalStorage to transfer data between components, which is not the correct way of doing things. If you happen to stumble upon OP's problem and you're doing that, make sure to study a little bit about sharing data between components.
The most common ways are Context API, Redux and passing data down as props.

You can read more about context [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: Yes, but I need to update the Wishlist count, whenever an Item is added to Wishlist. Like when you click heart icon on Twitter the number increases immediately but when I remove wishlist from dependancy array. I need to refresh to see the correct number

Comment: uhmm, are you updating the localstorage from another component/page? If so, that is not the correct approach. Try looking into context API, redux or passing it down as props.

Comment: if you're updating the wishlist from the same component, just call setWishList when you call the handler by clicking on the heart. There is no need to use the useEffect for that purpose

Comment: As you have suggested resolved the issue by using Redux for wishlist

Comment: Good job! I'd say Context API is a bit more modern approach, but redux works just fine! Maybe take a look into it later and choose what works best for you

Answer (score 0):

Here you have add **wishlist** in dependency array of useEffect and in that you have added condition  `if (wishlistStorage.length > 0) {   setWishlist(wishlistStorage); }` , because setting again the wishlist it will cause re-render and again useEffect will be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the wishlist from the dependencies

```
     React.useEffect(() => {
     if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
       const wishlistStorage =
       localStorage.getItem("wishlist") === null
       ? []
       : [...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("wishlist"))];

     if (wishlistStorage.length > 0) {
       setWishlist(wishlistStorage);
  }
}


}, []);
```

Comment: Removing wishlist from dependancy array, the Wishlist count doesn't increase when I add something new to the Wishlist unless I refresh the page. However, removing an item from Wishlist decreases the number from the Wishlist

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, and you need this only for the initial render, then you can simply remove `wishlist` from the dependency array.

```js
const [wishlist, setWishlist] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
   if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
     const wishlistStorage =
     localStorage.getItem("wishlist") === null
     ? []
     : [...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("wishlist"))];

     if (wishlistStorage.length > 0) {
       setWishlist(wishlistStorage);
     }
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: when I remove wishlist from dependancy array, the Wishlist count doesn't increase when I add something new to the Wishlist, unless I refresh the page. However, removing an item from Wishlist decreases the number from the Wishlist

Comment: TBH it really comes down to the structure of your comp. What we usually want to do is update the relevant state when adding/removing the item, and not in a `useEffect`. `useEffect` is normally used to act upon a change, not to induce it.

Answer (score 0):

You use `wishlist` as the deps of `useEffect` hooks, when the `wishlist` cache exists, `wishlistStorage` is an object parsed from the local storage JSON string. Then, you call `setWishlist(wishlistStorage)`, cause the hook re-render, the `wishlist` will have a new reference. The `useEffect` will execute again when its dependencies changes. That's why re-render infinitely.

You could use [lazy initial state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state)

> The `initialState` argument is the state used during the initial render. In subsequent renders, it is disregarded. If the initial state is the result of an expensive computation, you may provide a function instead, which will be executed only on the initial render

Use the cache from the local storage to initial your state if it exists, otherwise, returns a default value.

E.g:

```js
const [wishlist, setWishlist] = React.useState(() => {
 if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    const wishlistStorage =
       localStorage.getItem("wishlist") === null
       ? []
       : [...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("wishlist"))];
    return wishlistStorage;
  }
  return [];
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using setWishlist in useEffect that's observe wishlist, that's why it's lead you to infinity loop cuz when wishlist value changed it will execute the code in useEffect again and again so for my solution i saw localStorage in useEffect i would think it's would be only checked in first render, so you can simply remove [wishlist] -> []

```
  const [wishlist, setWishlist] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
     if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
       const wishlistStorage =
       localStorage.getItem("wishlist") === null
       ? []
       : [...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("wishlist"))];

     if (wishlistStorage.length > 0) {
       setWishlist(wishlistStorage);
  }
}


}, []);
```

Comment: I need to update the Wishlist count whenever an Item is added to Wishlist. Like when you click heart icon on Twitter the number increases immediately but when I remove wishlist from dependancy array. I need to refresh to see the correct number